# Calculation of Complex Number with exponent

Tags: complex-numbers

$\frac{(1+i)^{10}}{(1-i\sqrt{3})^9}$

What will be the computational technique here to calculate this complex number ? Will it be binomial or something ?

Comment: Turn the numerator and denominator into the form  $e^{i(something)}$

Answer (score 1):

@ask: There is an 'obvious' way to approach this. Write $\frac{(1+i)^{10}}{(1i\sqrt{3})^{9}} \\ = \frac{(\sqrt2 \cdot \text{cis}(\pi /4))^{10}}{(2\cdot cis(5\pi /3))^{9}} \\ = 1/16\cdot \text{cis}(10\pi /4 - 45\pi/3) \\ = 1/16\cdot \text{cis}(-\pi/2) \\ = -i/16.$

This just uses the identity that $(\text{cis}(x))^{\alpha}\cdot (\text{cis}(y))^{\beta} = \text{cis}(\alpha x + \beta y)$.